# Bulk download files from AWS server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, aws

I would like to download all the files for a MOOC course. I believe the directory the files are in has private access, while the files have public access.

The server is an AWS server so I understand they have a CLI.

So what would the approach be, on Linux/Ubuntu, for downloading the files with the AWS CLI?

but secondly, can this be done with just a bash script?

Is there a way to print all the files in a directory if you only have access to the files?

I don't need the full script, just a workaround to get a list of all files in the directory: https://s3.amazonaws.com/edx-course-spdx-kiczales/HTC/

should look something like this:

```
more-arithmetic-expression-starter.rkt
more-arithmetic-expression-solution.rkt
tile-starter.rkt
tile-solution.rkt
compare-images-starter.rkt
compare-images-solution.rkt
more-foo-evaluation-starter.rkt
...
```

Anyway, I already went through manually and found each name of the file in the directory, but since I might complete more courses and they will more often than not host material files in the same manner, I would love if there was a bulk approach to downloading files from a (AWS) server.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of files to download, just save it as a file (let’s call it `files.txt`) and then run this command:

```
< files.txt xargs -I{} wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/edx-course-spdx-kiczales/HTC/{}
```

> So what would the approach be, on Linux/Ubuntu, for downloading the files with the AWS CLI?

There is a lot of ways with `wget` being one of the most basic ones.

> but secondly, can this be done with just a bash script?

Why, if a single command can do this?

> Is there a way to print all the files in a directory if you only have access to the files?

If the owner is blocking that (as in this case), you cannot do it simply. How did you get the list of files you presented in your question actually?

> I would love if there was a bulk approach to downloading files from a (AWS) server.

You are barking up the wrong tree, you should ask the owner of the server instance. You cannot easily access any Linux server in the world just by knowing it is a Linux server. Yes, there are [black-hat hackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hat_(computer_security)) trying to do so but Linux is designed to be secure, so not allowing that.

Comment: Thankyou, but lets say I don't know the names of the files, just that there is a directory with some files... is there a way to obtain said filenames given only the directory (like `ls`), much in the same way one could read all the ingredients in a food product they do not own?

Comment: @jackw11111 Then you can only guess them hoping that the server does not count unsuccessful attempts and ban you afterwards…